# After Refresh the page it result Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel

This is my panel.blade.php

```
<form action="/loginfunction" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username:" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password:" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" >
                </form>
```

this is the controller of loginfunction or login

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $username = $request->input('username');
        $password = $request->input('password');


        $results = DB::table('user')
            ->where('username', $username)
            ->where('password', $password)
            ->get();


        if ($results->count() > 0) {
            echo 'success';



            return redirect('/dashboard')
                ->with('session_user', $results);

        }




    }
```

After i click the button it will display the username into the dashboard.blade.php

the code is their to fetch the session_user in the loginController

```
@foreach(Session::get('session_user') as $user)
    {{ $user->username }}
@endforeach
```

Then if i try to refresh the page of dashboard.blade.php
the session_user is not displaying and the error 
**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Then the Controller of dashboard.blade.php and the code is here

```
public function dashboard(Request $request) 
{

    return view('dashboard');

}
```

The problem is why i got error when i refresh the page of dashboard.blade.php?
i set already the session their..

Thank you guys.

Comment: Extra hint: `->where('username', $username)->where('password', $password)` __never ever__ save raw passwords in your db. Use password encryption/hashes instead.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer thanks for extra hint..

Comment: dashboard is different and redirect to dashboard is different. when you redirect a variable is available `session_user` but when you refresh that code is different. You are not setting session here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a current user in session on a controller

```
if ($results->count() > 0) {
    echo 'success';
    Session::put('session_user',$results);
    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

> If you are new in laravel than better to use laravel inbuilt
>   Authentication it gives much-inbuilt functionality like login,
>   register, forget a password and you can access your login user data in
>   anywhere of your project with a simple syntax.

Comment: yah. im new in laravel. 1day :)

Comment: You need to add use Session; top of the file

Comment: @SirGeorge it's not a good method for login register in laravel you can use inbuilt auth method of laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication